# Limiting column width in datagrid for command button columns

Tags: react-admin

in React-Admin I want to limit the width of the columns that show edit, show buttons in the datagrid

I know I can use styles to set the width of other cells like TextFields, but cant find a way to do this with buttons

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZpLf.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `Datagrid` you can use the `headerClassName` `cellClassName` props to style both the cell in the header row and in body rows as described in the docs under section [Datagrid/CSS-Api](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/List.html#css-api-1)

```
<ShowButton
   headerClassName={classes.hiddenOnSmallScreens}
   cellClassName={classes.hiddenOnSmallScreens}
/>
```

***EDIT**

Obviously this approach doesn't work when using typescript, probably a bug - you can work around it in this way:

```
const usePostListActionToolbarStyles = makeStyles({
  toolbar: {
    alignItems: "center",
    display: "flex",
    marginTop: -1,
    marginBottom: -1
  }
});

const PostListActionToolbar = ({ children, ...props }) => {
  const classes = usePostListActionToolbarStyles();
  return (
    <div className={classes.toolbar}>
      {Children.map(children, (button) => cloneElement(button, props))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

and then inside your Datagrid:

```
<Datagrid>
   //...fields
  <PostListActionToolbar>
      <ShowButton/>
      <EditButton/>
  </PostListActionToolbar>
</Datagrid>
```

Comment: Thanks Kia Kaha but I am not looking to style the TextFields, but the button fields such as <ShowButton />
<EditButton />

Comment: I have copied you the example from the docs.  This approach works with whatever type of Datagrid column you are styling - whether a Field or a Button or something else. Please, read the docs section I have referenced first.

Comment: Thanks, Its not a type that is recognised for buttons in TypeScript. I get the following: "ype '{ headerClassName: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props & Props"

Comment: I see, check out the updated answer - if this is also not solving your problem maybe you should start an issue on github because the first approach works fine in plain js and is ts definitons are missing it by mistake.